# Dns server: how can I configure a dns server to track down a pc name in a dhcp enviroment?

Tags: dns

I have a dhcp in my home and I would like to setup a dns server too.
I would like to implement a linux solution but I think I can't get hands on without understanding - very superficially - if I can achieve such result.

My pc (hostname: test) gets a 192.168.1.7 from dhcp.
Its dns server is my router (192.168.1.1).
How can the router relate my ip change (as soon as the lease is over) to my hostname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most assuredly your router is not a DNS server, it's a DNS forwarder/resolver. It resolves external DNS queries for internal clients but does not host any DNS zones.

You'll need to install and configure an internal DNS server and zone for your internal clients and configure your DHCP server to register the A records on behalf of the DHCP clients. You'll want to configure the DHCP options for the correct DNS suffix (to match your DNS zone) so that the zone will be correctly populated with the A records for your internal DHCP clients.

Comment: So... Why if I set my router in both clients' dns configuration and ping each other using name it works?

Comment: Are you pinging the FQDN of each client or the NetBIOS name of each client? What OS are the clients running? Does your router host a zone for your internal DNS namespace? If not, then the clients are able to ping each other via broadcasts or LLMNR.

Answer (score 0):

If you install a NS server on your PC, you would want to change it from a dynamic address (DHCP) to a static one.  This way you won't have to reconfigure DHCP every time your PC changes its IP address.